# Real Analysis - Uniform Continuity and boundedness

Tags: real-analysis

Working through some Real Analysis self study from a friends notes to prepare for next year.  Trying to gather some insight on how this proof would work?

> Suppose that $f \colon R \to R$ is differentiable everywhere, and that $f' \colon R \to R$ is bounded. Prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous.
>
> Find an example of a function $f \colon I \to R$ such that $I$ is some interval of your choice (possibly unbounded), $f$ is uniformly continuous, $f'$ exists everywhere (except at the endpoints of $I$, if $I$ is closed), and $f'$ is NOT bounded.

Doesn't differentiability imply continuity?  Or is that the other way around? Could use some help understanding here.

Answer (score 2):

For the first part, to show $f$ is uniformly continuous,
use fundamental theorem of calculus.
If $|f'|$ is bounded by $C$, then
$$
| f(x) - f(y) | = \left| \int_x^y f' \right| \le \int_x^y |f'|
\le \int_x^y C = C|x - y|
$$
You may recognize this as "Lipschitz continuity", and it implies uniform continuity pretty easily.

For the second part, you need to find an example function $f$ that is differentiable and uniformly continuous but whose derivative is unbounded.
Recall that a continuous function on a compact domain is uniformly continuous.  So $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is uniformly continuous.  However, the derivative $f'(x) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$ is unbounded on this interval.

And to your last question, yes, a differentiable function is continuous.  (But the derivative of a differentiable function need not be continuous!)

Comment: What version of the fundamental theorem of Calculus are you assuming? That is, are you using Lebesgue integration or sticking to Riemann integration?

Comment: @T.A.E. Riemann integration, I suppose.  If $f$ is a differentiable function whose derivative is integrable, then $f(x) = f(a) + \int_a^x f'(x) \; dx$.

Comment: Do you know that $f'$ is Riemann integrable and that $f(x)=f(a)+\int_{a}^{x}f'(t)dt$? That's not the usual statement of the fundamental theorem for Riemann integrals.

Comment: @T.A.E. I don't know what statement you're using, but it's certainly equivalent.  It's what Wikipedia gives as the second fundamental theorem of calculus [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Second_part).

Answer (score 0):

To prove the function is uniformly continuous use the mean value theorem since the derivative is bounded.